# moved domains and 301 redirects are not working...?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have recently moved our website from the old domain to a new domain.  The old domain is now empty except for the .htaccess file which is as follows (eg):

redirect 301 /examplepage.html https://www.newdomain.com/examplepage.html

However, when we test the old link it isn't redirecting.

We've tried tech support from the domain people, but they have given us a couple of bogus sounding excuses (like the old domain has no files other than the .htaccess).  The latest reason they suggested was that the old domain no longer has a certificate installed so the https pages aren't redirecting.

To be fair, we do get a different result if searching for a page using http/https:

for HTTP we get "Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server."

for HTTPS we get "This site can’t be reached [www.domainname.co.uk](http://www.domainname.co.uk) unexpectedly closed the connection.
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED"

Any ideas where we're going wrong or how to fix this...?

Comment: did you enable the rewriteengine? `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>` (for apache running server)

Comment: @RamondeVries The OP is not using mod_rewrite ("rewriteengine") in the question. `Redirect` is a mod_alias directive.

Comment: Could it be that you are looking at cached results of previous requests when the old domain was still in operation?